# Including the final character in text output from a NSScanner

Tags: objective-c, nsscanner

I am using a NSScanner to detect text bound by [square brackets] in a string, and convert it into HTML hyperlinks. I hope to turn convert this text in the following way:

```
This [is an] example of the [text] I'm using
```

should convert to

```
This <a href = "is an">is an</a> example of the <a href = "text">text</a> I'm using
```

I've implemented a NSScanner, but in order to make it work properly, I need to extract both the first and second of the square brackets.

Here's the current state of my code:

```
NSScanner *theScanner;
NSString *text = nil;
theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:stringWithBrackets];

NSString *stringWithoutBrackets;
while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    [theScanner scanUpToString:@"[" intoString:NULL];
    [theScanner scanUpToString:@"]" intoString:&text];

<BREAK>
```

At this breakpoint, I have a string returned, which does *not* contain the closing bracket. So, for the example text string shown above, the contents of NSString *text at the first breakpoint is

```
[is an
```

In order to properly manipulate the string, I need to work with both the opening and closing bracket.

Essentially, my question is: how do I advance the NSScanner on *one* character, and include that character into the variable 'text'?

Comment: May I ask why you "unaccepted" my answer again? Is there a problem with it?

Comment: Maybe, I'm just testing it now :) Will put it back when I know it works. I shouldn't have accepted it until testing it!

Comment: OK, that is fair! It thought you had tested it before accepting. - Please let me know if there is any problem, then I will try to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the `]` character with `scanString`:

```
if ([theScanner scanString:@"]" intoString:NULL]) {
    text = [text stringByAppendingString:@"]"];
} else {
    // Next character is not ']'
}
```

The `else` case would only happen if there is no matching `]` character. `text` contains the part from `[` to the end of the string in that case.

Alternatively, you could use `NSRegularExpression` and e.g. the `matchesInString` method which returns an array of all ranges in the string matching the regular expression.